# An incorrect type of extension has been requested

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to customize the business logic of sales order in Acumatica. Here is the code that i wrote

```
protected void SOLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

  InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOLine.inventoryID>(cache, row);

  if(item != null)
  {
    InventoryItemExt itemExt = orderitem.Cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
    if(item.InventoryID == row.InventoryID && itemExt.GarmentType == true)
    {
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.orderQty>(this.orderitem.Cache, null, false);
    }
  }
}

public PXSelect<InventoryItem> Inventory;
```

and the error that I am getting is this

[Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGAmw.png)

I used this code previously couple of times in other graph and there wasn't any problem. And I am wondering what did I miss for this graph, is it because its extension graph or something, I am not really sure

Thank you in advance for the help

**EDIT**
The error I get after change the event to RowSelected event
And the code after edit is below

```
protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (SOLine)e.Row;

  InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOLine.inventoryID>(cache, row);

  if(item != null)
  {
    InventoryItemExt itemExt = Inventory.Cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
    if(item.InventoryID == row.InventoryID && itemExt.GarmentType == true)
    {
      PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.orderQty>(this.orderitem.Cache, null, false);
    }
  }
```

Is it bug or the problem is in my code?

[The latest error trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPooh.png)

Comment: I would recommend enabling or disabling fields in RowSelected (not FieldUpdated). Also, don't forget to pass in the row into SetEnabled or you will enable/disable all rows (not just the row you are checking)

Comment: I tried to use RowSelected and still getting the same error

Comment: yes the error is unrelated to my comment. My comment was just general in usage of SetEnabled. For the GetExtension call in your update just change it to ....  InventoryItemExt itemExt = item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();

Comment: the error now become, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: debug and see which object is null. I don't know what orderitem.cache is but would think the SetEnabled would be the cache of RowSelected... something like this.... PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.orderQty>(cache, row, false);

Comment: Yes, if debug it and run from visual studio, there is nothing wrong with the code, just need to reset the IIS. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is the FieldUpdated event handler of SOLine.InventoryID:

```
protected void SOLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
[...]
```

The error trace call stack you posted indicates the error originates from another event handler:
[image: error trace]

Check the SOLine RowSelected event handler instead of the SOLine InventoryID field updated handler. Trace indicates exception is raised at line 73 of SOOrderEntry.cs

Not related to your error: when creating extension class, it is recommended to give a different filename than base classes. SOOrderEntry.cs is the base class file in Acumatica, you can name your file SOOrderEntryExt.cs to differentiate it from the base class.

**EDIT**, your DataView might not be of InventoryItem type, try:

```
Base.Caches[typeof(InventoryItem)].GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item)
```

**EDIT 2** full code

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    #region UsrCustomField
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Custom Field")]
    public virtual string UsrCustomField { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrCustomField : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}

public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
    protected void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOLine soLine = e.Row as SOLine;

        if (soLine != null)
        {
            InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOLine.inventoryID>(cache, soLine);

            if (item != null)
            {
                InventoryItemExt itemExt = Base.Caches[typeof(InventoryItem)].GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
                PXTrace.WriteInformation(string.Concat("Success = ", (itemExt != null).ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use rowselected event, and still getting the same error. Also I will change the name to of the graph, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: From the trace you posted, the error has always been from RowSelected. However the code provided in the question is FieldUpdated which is unrelated to RowSelected. Can you post code where the error is coming from?

Comment: alright, I see you posted the new trace which does point to FieldUpdated

Comment: I already edit the post with my code after I change it to RowSelected

Comment: I tried to do that earlier, and the error I was getting is this 

error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group' in file: Code#SOOrderEntry(53)

thats why i decide to use PXSelect

Comment: I posted full code, it is working for me, no compilation or runtime code error.

Comment: I think its buggy, I will post the screenshot of the error trace in my post. Would you recommend me something on what to reset or something?

Comment: From the latest error trace you posted, it seems like you have 2 extensions for InventoryItemExt with the same name in 2 different namespaces and trying to mix them. This is not supported, you should make sure you use only 1 of the DAC extension. Don't use the one from my example, substitute it with your own.

Comment: It could also be the case that you need to reset IIS because an old customization is stuck in memory. To do that, open a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) with Admin rights and use command 'iisreset'.

Comment: If I run it from visual studio it work as intended, thank you very much. So I need to reset the IIS. Thank you again for the help